# How to prove $\int_{0} ^{1}{\sqrt{1-x^4}dx}=\frac{1}{12}\sqrt {\frac{2}{\pi}}(\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right))^2$?

Tags: calculus, integration, gamma-function, beta-function

To prove ,

$$\int_{0} ^{1}{\sqrt{1-x^4}dx}=\frac{1}{12}\sqrt {\frac{2}{\pi}}(\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right))^2$$

When we substitute $x^4$ with t

we get the equation
$$\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^1t^{\frac{-3}{4}}(1-t)^{\frac{1}{2}}dt$$
the expression is in the forms of the beta functions, But I am not able to solve ahead.

Comment: Expand Beta in terms of Gamma.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I will try to expand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$I=\frac { 1 }{ 4 } \int _{ 0 }^{ 1 } t^{ \frac { -3 }{ 4 }  }(1-t)^{ \frac { 1 }{ 2 }  }dt$$

Now, on using Beta function, we get $$I=\frac { 1 }{ 4 } B\left( \frac { 1 }{ 4 } ,\frac { 3 }{ 2 }  \right) $$

Now, we use the relation of Beta and gamma function. $$I=\frac { 1 }{ 4 } \frac { \Gamma \left( \frac { 1 }{ 4 }  \right) \Gamma \left( \frac { 3 }{ 2 }  \right)  }{ \Gamma \left( \frac { 7 }{ 4 }  \right)  } $$

Now, we use the formula: $\Gamma \left( n+1 \right) =n\Gamma \left( n \right) $

$$I=\frac { 1 }{ 4 } \frac { \Gamma \left( \frac { 1 }{ 4 }  \right) \Gamma \left( \frac { 1 }{ 2 }  \right) \times \frac { 1 }{ 2 }  }{ \frac { 3 }{ 4 } \Gamma \left( \frac { 3 }{ 4 }  \right)  } $$

We use this value: $\Gamma \left( \frac { 1 }{ 2 }  \right) =\sqrt { \pi  } $

$$I=\frac { \sqrt { \pi  }  }{ 6 } \frac { \Gamma \left( \frac { 1 }{ 4 }  \right)  }{ \Gamma \left( \frac { 3 }{ 4 }  \right)  } $$

$$I=\frac { \sqrt { \pi  }  }{ 6 } \frac { { \left( \Gamma \left( \frac { 1 }{ 4 }  \right)  \right)  }^{ 2 } }{ \Gamma \left( \frac { 1 }{ 4 }  \right) \Gamma \left( \frac { 3 }{ 4 }  \right)  } $$

Now, by [Euler's Reflection Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General), we get $$I=\frac { \sqrt { \pi  }  }{ 6 } \frac { { \left( \Gamma \left( \frac { 1 }{ 4 }  \right)  \right)  }^{ 2 } }{ \frac { \pi  }{ \sin { \left( \frac { \pi  }{ 4 }  \right)  }  }  } $$

$$\boxed{\therefore \int _{ 0 }^{ 1 }{ \sqrt { 1-x^{ 4 } } dx } =\frac { 1 }{ 12 } \sqrt { \frac { 2 }{ \pi  }  } { \left( \Gamma \left( \frac { 1 }{ 4 }  \right)  \right)  }^{ 2 }}$$